# UPDATE con varias condiciones MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy nuevo con bases de datos y tengo un problema un cruce de información que quiero llevar a cabo.

Tengo dos tablas una llamada **NRC_NACIMIENTOS** y la otra **CURP_YUCATAN**, lo que me piden es ACTUALIZAR la columna PE_CURP en la tabla **NRC_NACIMIENTOS** con el valor correspondiente de la tabla **CURP_YUCATAN** si las columnas **PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO**, **PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO** Y **PE_NOMBRES** concuerdan con los valores de **NRC_NACIMIENTOS**.

Ambas tablas se encuentran en la misma base de datos y las columnas tienen el mismo nombre.

Tengo ésto de código:

```
UPDATE NRC_NACIMIENTOS
JOIN CURP_YUCATAN
SET NRC_NACIMIENTOS.PE_CURP = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_CURP
IF nrc_nacimientos.PE_NOMBRES = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_NOMBRES AND nrc_nacimientos.PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO AND nrc_nacimientos.PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO;
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, espero haber sido claro.

Comment: Por favor agrega la consulta SQL que llevas al momento

Comment: Cual es el problema que tuviste haciendo esta consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta sintaxis es un estándar

```
UPDATE NRC_NACIMIENTOS  
 SET NRC_NACIMIENTOS.PE_CURP = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_CURP 
 FROM NRC_NACIMIENTOS JOIN CURP_YUCATAN ON nrc_nacimientos.PE_NOMBRES = 
 CURP_YUCATAN.PE_NOMBRES AND nrc_nacimientos.PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO = 
 CURP_YUCATAN.PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO AND nrc_nacimientos.PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO;
```

Aunque en MariaDB la sintaxis es esta

```
UPDATE NRC_NACIMIENTOS, CURP_YUCATAN
SET NRC_NACIMIENTOS.PE_CURP = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_CURP
WHERE nrc_nacimientos.PE_NOMBRES = 
 CURP_YUCATAN.PE_NOMBRES AND nrc_nacimientos.PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO = 
 CURP_YUCATAN.PE_PRIMERAPELLIDO AND nrc_nacimientos.PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO = CURP_YUCATAN.PE_SEGUNDOAPELLIDO;
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, recuerda que una explicación que acompañe al código siempre hace que el aporte quedé más claro

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a probarlo.

Comment: Me aparece el "FROM" subrayado en rojo y el siguiente error al querer ejecutar la query:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM NRC_NACIMIENTOS_PRUEBA  JOIN CURP_YUCATAN.PE_NOMBRES  ON NRC_NACIMIENTOS_PR' at line 3

Comment: @DPeña, había un pequeño error en la sentencia, mis disculpas. Pero viendo que se trata de MariaDB, te he puesto la segunda opción.